# Parsing a file path - One column with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server, parse-platform

I have a table with one column titled "File Path" and I need to parse the file paths into three separate columns...
I have been using this

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @STR = 'NEED ANSWER FOR THIS SPACE'

SELECT LEFT(@STR,(CHARINDEX('|',@STR)-1)) AS FILEPATH,
    RIGHT(@STR,LEN(@STR) - ((CHARINDEX('|',@STR)-1))-1) AS NUMBER_OF_RECORDS,
    @STR
```

But I don't know how to declare the variable `@STR` as the entire column... Any help would be huge.

Comment: Can't you make your select against your table and field instead of using @STR? I mean, do SELECT LEFT(FilePath_Field,(CHARINDEX('|',@STR)-1)) AS FILEPATH , RIGHT(FilePath_Field,LEN(@STR) - ((CHARINDEX('|',@STR)-1))-1) AS NUMBER_OF_RECORDS , FilePath_Field FROM Your_Table

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT
    FILEPATH = LEFT(@STR, (CHARINDEX('|', st.FilePath) - 1)), 
    NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = RIGHT(st.FilePath, LEN(st.FilePath) - ((CHARINDEX('|', st.FilePath) - 1)) - 1), 
    st.FilePath
FROM 
    dbo.SomeTable st;
```